# User interaction disabled for parent viewController when removed from child ViewController

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiview, uiviewcontroller, swift3

I am using below code to move from left to right.

```
   let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate

    appDelegate.rightNavController?.view.frame =  CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: (appDelegate.window?.frame.size.width)!, height: (appDelegate.window?.frame.size.height)!)

    self.removeNavigationController()

    appDelegate.rightNavController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: leftmenuViewController)
    appDelegate.rightNavController?.navigationBar.isHidden = true
    baseController.addChildViewController(appDelegate.rightNavController!)

    baseController.view.addSubview((appDelegate.rightNavController?.view)!)

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions(), animations: {

    }, completion: { finished in
        appDelegate.rightNavController?.view.frame =  CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 320, height: 568)
    })
```

my view hierarchy in side menu is UIView->UiTableView.I have added tap gesture on UIView to dismiss side menu.
Below is the code used to dismiss:(tap gesture method)

```
   self.willMove(toParentViewController: nil)

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions(), animations: {
        self.view.frame = CGRect(x:-self.view.frame.size.width, y: 0 ,width : self.view.frame.size.width, height :self.view.frame.size.height)

    }, completion: { finished in

        self.removeFromParentViewController()
        self.view.removeFromSuperview()
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate

        appDelegate.rightNavController = nil

        appDelegate.rightNavController?.view = nil



    })
```

Now the issue is when child viewController is removed, parent view controller user interaction is disabled.

Any help to solve this issue.

Comment: Question is not clear,

Comment: After removing childviewcontroller parent view user interaction is disabled

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what you're trying to achieve from the wording of the question but I would look for the isUserInteractionEnabled property on the view that's causing you trouble.

Also, maybe have a look to yourView.layer.zPosition. The view getting the interaction is the one with the highest zPosition value. Everyone defaults to zPosition = 0. All else being equal, the order in which the views where added will dictate who gets the events.